# How can I ensure FLoC is blocked in chromium?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, chromium, tracking

I use Chromium 89.0 on a Devuan GNU/Linux system. I've recently heard about Google's FLoC tracking mechanism (through the [announcement of it being disabled in Brave](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=26765084#26765247)), and I was wondering - how can I make sure it's disabled, or blocked, in Chromium? I have the EFF Privacy Badger extension installed - is that enough to do the trick?

Comment: You should read [this page](https://spreadprivacy.com/block-floc-with-duckduckgo/) and try to get `DuckDuckGo extension`.

Comment: @C0deDaedalus: It doesn't say whether EFF privacy badger is enough, or whether their extension does something else that's special.